# Google Sheets API V4 VB Net BatchUpdate - Upload

Tags: vb.net, google-sheets-api, .net-4.7.2

I am attempting to load the contents of a CSV file directly to an existing Google Sheet using the batch update method.

The problem is that my code is only uploading the last record, but from what I can tell the request object has all the data.

So far I am able to loop through the CSV file and cast each row to a Google Sheets ValueRange and add each ValueRange to a data object in order to apply it to the RequestBody required by the Google Sheets API.
This is all based on the API documentation available from Google.
[Google Sheets API V4 Batch Update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

I tossed in a few Message Boxes just to see what is happening in the background.

Below is the code I am using currently, and a sample set of data you can put into a csv file to run.

It appears that I am missing something with the upload request itself, if anyone has any input or experience with this I can't seem to get past this.

*Note: this code is simply a VB .Net winform app with a single button added to the form.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Sheets.v4
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data
Imports Data = Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data

Public Class Form1
    Dim ClientID As String = "<GOOGLE CLIENT>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    Dim ClientSecret As String = "<CLIENT SECRET>"
    Dim Scopes As String() = {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets}
    Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = ClientID,
                                                                                                             .ClientSecret = ClientSecret},
                                                                                                             Scopes, "user",
                                                                                                             CancellationToken.None).Result

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim r As Integer = 1
        Dim oblist = New List(Of Object)
        Dim sheetsService As SheetsService = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer With {
              .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
              .ApplicationName = "Google-SheetsSample/0.1"
          })

        Dim spreadsheetId As String = "<SPREADSHEET ID>"
        Dim valueInputOption As String = "RAW"
        Dim valueRanges As ValueRange = New ValueRange()
        Dim data As List(Of Data.ValueRange) = New List(Of Data.ValueRange)

        Dim tfp As New TextFieldParser("<PATH TO CSV FILE I WANT TO UPLOAD>")
        tfp.SetDelimiters(",")
        tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        'tfp.ReadLine() ' skip header
        While tfp.EndOfData = False

            Dim fields = tfp.ReadFields()

            Dim range2 As String = "A" & r  ' range to update
            valueRanges.MajorDimension = "ROWS" '"ROWS";//COLUMNS
            valueRanges.Range = range2 ' apply range to ValueRnage

            ' My csv has 12 fields 
            oblist = New List(Of Object)() From {
             fields(0), fields(1), fields(2), fields(3), fields(4), fields(5), fields(6), fields(7), fields(8), fields(9), fields(10), fields(11)
                   }
            valueRanges.Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From { ' add list of objects pulled from TextFieldParser to ValueRange
            oblist
    }
            data.Add(valueRanges) ' Add valueRange to data for RequestBody
            r += 1 ' Increment Range
        End While

        MsgBox("Count of value ranges in data object : " & data.Count)

        Dim requestBody As Data.BatchUpdateValuesRequest = New Data.BatchUpdateValuesRequest()
        requestBody.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption
        requestBody.Data = data

        MsgBox("Request body data : " & requestBody.Data.Count)

        Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchUpdateRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId)
        Dim response As Data.BatchUpdateValuesResponse = request.Execute()

        MsgBox("Count of Rows uploaded to google sheet : " & response.TotalUpdatedRows)
    End Sub

End Class
```

CSV - EXAMPLE -

Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4,Column 5,Column 6,Column 7,Column 8,Column 9,Column 10,Column 11,Column 12
ex12,ex34,ex56,ex78,ex100,ex122,ex144,ex166,ex188,ex210,ex232,ex254
ex13,ex35,ex57,ex79,ex101,ex123,ex145,ex167,ex189,ex211,ex233,ex255
ex14,ex36,ex58,ex80,ex102,ex124,ex146,ex168,ex190,ex212,ex234,ex256
ex15,ex37,ex59,ex81,ex103,ex125,ex147,ex169,ex191,ex213,ex235,ex257
ex16,ex38,ex60,ex82,ex104,ex126,ex148,ex170,ex192,ex214,ex236,ex258
ex17,ex39,ex61,ex83,ex105,ex127,ex149,ex171,ex193,ex215,ex237,ex259
ex18,ex40,ex62,ex84,ex106,ex128,ex150,ex172,ex194,ex216,ex238,ex260
ex19,ex41,ex63,ex85,ex107,ex129,ex151,ex173,ex195,ex217,ex239,ex261
ex20,ex42,ex64,ex86,ex108,ex130,ex152,ex174,ex196,ex218,ex240,ex262
ex21,ex43,ex65,ex87,ex109,ex131,ex153,ex175,ex197,ex219,ex241,ex263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I create one code .. The difference is only you pass List to ValueRange whereas there should be IList  ..
But for conversion from list to Ilist I used objList.ToList () and I don't know it's drawback you need to check

And also you have to create new object of valueRange within while loop

```
 Dim sheetId = FileId
                Dim service = GetGoogleAPPSheetService()

                Dim val_range As ValueRange
                Dim DataList As List(Of ValueRange) = New List(Of ValueRange)

                Dim I As Integer = 0

                Dim objList As List(Of Object)
                Dim objMainList As List(Of IList(Of Object))

                Dim objIlIst As IList(Of Object)
                Dim objImainList As IList(Of IList(Of Object))


                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

                    I += 1

                    val_range = New ValueRange

                    val_range.Range = "A" & I.ToString

                    objList = New List(Of Object) From {dr(0).ToString, dr(1).ToString}

                    objMainList = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {objList.ToList()}

                    val_range.Values = objMainList.ToList

                    DataList.Add(val_range)

                Next

                Dim req_body As BatchUpdateValuesRequest = New BatchUpdateValuesRequest
                req_body.ValueInputOption = "RAW"
                req_body.Data = DataList.ToList

                Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchUpdateRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(req_body, sheetId)
                Dim response As BatchUpdateValuesResponse = request.Execute

                MsgBox("Count of Rows uploaded to google sheet : " & response.TotalUpdatedRows)



            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
```